# find a row from DynamoDB w/o hash and range key and delete it

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

Is there a way to remove a record/row from DynamoDB without using the hash key and range key?

Here is my table look like:
[image]

I have a value of instance_id and based on that I would delete the row but getting errors:

here is the code I am using:

```
            table.delete_item(
                Key={
                    'instance_id':'i-0b2b314a'
                }
            )
```

Answer (score 4):

The [`delete_item()` documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Client.delete_item) says:

> Deletes a single item in a table **by primary key**.

So, it is not possible to delete by a value that is not the primary key.

You would need to scan (expensive in terms of RCUs!) for the rows with that value, then delete the returned items.

Comment: Indeed. Also, if this is a common thing you'll need to do - you often need to delete items by their "instance_id" attribute, you can also create a secondary index for this attribute. This will allow you to efficiently find the hash key given an instance_id.